# jQuery cycle plugin appears to show second image first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the cycle.js plugin for a slideshow, its pretty lightweight and a great plugin.

However, the image I use first doesnt show first, it shows the second image first, this is a problem as there is a navigation beneath the slideshow.

jQ:

```
$('#slideShow').after('<div id="ssnav">').cycle({ 
                    delay: -12000,
                    next:   '#next2', 
                    prev:   '#prev2',
                    timeout:  8000,
                    pager: '#ssnav',
                 });
```

HTML structure:

```
<div>
    <img src="#_" />
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="#_" />
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="#_" />
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

You get the picture, but it shows the second div first - how can i counteract this?

Comment: do you have a live example ?

Comment: can you please create fiddle..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the option "delay" that you used:
delay: additional delay (in ms) for first transition (hint: can be negative)

when you remove it, the slide-show will start at first one.

you can check options with small description from [this link](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)